# Initializing Database Connections with SQL Code in WebSphere 8

Tags: oracle, websphere, database-connection, datasource

Oracle WebLogic allows initializing database connections with SQL Code (s. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/jdbc_connection_pools.html#1127542). Is there any way to do this in WebSphere 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. See [WebSphere Application Server data source properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_jdbcdatasorprops.html?lang=en) page.

You need to check: `Validate new connections` and provide your SQL code in the: `Validation by SQL string` in the Data source properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works, but only one SQL validation statement seems to be allowed...? Moreover this feature is deprecated according to documentation.

Comment: @Dio You may try multiple statements with separator, or put them in the procedure (I've didn't test that). Yes, it is deprecated, but still supported in 8.x and 8.5.5.x. You may contact IBM Support asking, when it will be removed and what is the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the Connection validation by SQL query column of the Application programming model row in the [deprecation table](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rmig_depfeat.html#depv7) for the recommended alternative.  IBM support cannot provide you with a time frame for removal, as there is no fixed time frame for deprecated features to be removed.  At a minimum, the feature will not be removed for 2 releases after deprecation.  In this particular case, the feature was deprecated because the JDBC spec now defines similar capability.